# How to convert this sql query to laravel query ? from below query total sum is generated but i need sum according to customer's product

Tags: laravel

How to convert this sql query to laravel query ? from below query total sum is generated but i need sum according to customer's product

```
SELECT orders.id,orders.customer_id,orderdets.product_id,
SUM(orderdets.quantity) 
FROM orders,orderdets
WHERE orders.id=orderdets.order_id
AND  orderdets.product_id=11
GROUP BY orders.customer_id
;
```

Comment: Does the above query is the desired output you want in Laravel or there will be a change in this?

Comment: are you using models ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an Order model, and the following query could achieve what you want.

```
Order::select('orders.id', 'orders.customer_id', 'orderdets.product_id')
    ->sum('orderdets.quantity')
    ->leftJoin('orderdets', 'orders.id', '=', 'orderdets.order_id')
    ->where('product_id', $productId)
    ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subWeek())
    ->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
    ->groupBy('orders.customer_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Glad it helped, if it solved your issue please accept it as an answer :)

Comment: sorry to bother you again but how to add where between(dates) in created_at in orderdets

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer with sum aggregate

```
Order::leftJoin('orderdets','orders.id', '=','orderdets.order_id')
->sum('orderdets.quantity')
->select('orders.id','orders.customer_id','orderdets.product_id','orderdets.quantity')
->where('product_id', $productId) // <---- your product id go here
->groupBy('orders.customer_id')
->get();
```